# How to determine if a sequence of bits is positive or negative

Tags: c#, c++, c, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I have 2 sets of values. Each is in the range of -15 to + 15 including 0.

I managed to represent two numbers in 8 bits. 4 of those bits may belong to a negative set the other 4 positive.

Whenever I read that sequence of bits I want to be able to determine if the initial 4 bits are + or -.

Is there a way to accomplish this using bitwise operations for both packing and unpacking? or another clever way?

thanks in advance.

Update: Here's at some extend a sample of what I'm trying to achieve:

*out of those 31 values I need to represent only two, using 8 bits, say for example I have the numbers 14+ and 15+. They can be both positive or have one of each but they cannot be both negative. So 14 = 1110 and 15 = 1111 (Take all 0s out); bitsequence = 11101111
So when unpacking I know byte 239 = 11101111, actually represents numbers 14+ and 15+ respectively by parsing the bit sequence. However I'm having a hard time when either one of the numbers is negative.*

Comment: Pick a language.  The easiest way to do this in C and C++ has no equivalent in C#.

Comment: Also, you need 5 bits to represent the range [-15:15].

Comment: Feel free to use samples in c,c++,c#, etc I really don't mind which language.

Comment: Your description is confusing and unclear. How do you expect to represent 31 values with only 4 bits? You say "4 of those bits may belong to a negative set the other 4 positive" -- can they both be negative, or both positive, or do you always have one of each?

Comment: Jim, out of those 31 values I need to represent only two, using 8 bits, say for example I have the numbers 14+ and 15+. They can be both positive or have one of each but they cannot be both negative. So 14 = 1110 and 15 = 1111 (Take all 0s out); bitsequence = 11101111.

Comment: So when I'm unpacking I know byte 239 = 11101111, actually represents numbers 14+ and 15+ respectively by parsing the bit sequence. However I'm having a hard time when either one of the numbers is negative.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this really easily with a bitfield:

```
struct two_numbers
{
     signed char first : 4;
     signed char second : 4;
};
```

Then you can just compare to zero like normal:

```
two_numbers t = { 7, -5 };
if (t.first < 0 || t.second < 0) { ... }
```

Note, however, that a 4 bit field only allows values from -8 through 7, not -15 or 15.

Comment: I like the approach however I do really need it for -15 or 15.

Comment: @ealva: That's not a limitation of this approach, it's a limitation of what a *bit* is.  The range -15 to 15, inclusive, has 31 distinct integer values.  Four bits only give you 16 distinct patterns.  You can't fit 31 in 16 (refer to the [Pigeonhole Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) of information theory)

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you're using your 8-bit example, where you use the high-order bits to represent a negative number, and the low-order bits to represent a positive number.  If you mask your number against 0xF0, and the result is non-zero, then your number is negative.

Another way to approach the problem is to just use whatever method your language offers for a byte value.  Then, you don't need to do anything clever, just test if the value is less than zero.